# Application showing wifi warning Note4

Tags: java, android, android-studio, google-play-services, samsung-mobile

My app is not launching in Galaxy note 4. Works fine on rest of the devices.  It gives me a Internet error (Service not available standard activity launches) My Android monitor output is:

```
09-14 11:18:25.614 17353-17353/com.ppfa.stdtestca.release I/System.out: Sending WAIT chunk
09-14 11:18:25.614 17353-17353/com.ppfa.stdtestca.release W/ActivityThread: Application com.ppfa.stdtestca.release is waiting for the debugger on port 8100...
09-14 11:18:25.774 17353-17359/com.ppfa.stdtestca.release I/dalvikvm: Debugger is active
09-14 11:18:25.814 17353-17353/com.ppfa.stdtestca.release I/System.out: Debugger has connected
09-14 11:18:25.814 17353-17353/com.ppfa.stdtestca.release I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
09-14 11:18:26.024 17353-17353/com.ppfa.stdtestca.release I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
09-14 11:18:26.224 17353-17353/com.ppfa.stdtestca.release I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
09-14 11:18:26.414 17353-17353/com.ppfa.stdtestca.release I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
09-14 11:18:26.614 17353-17353/com.ppfa.stdtestca.release I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
09-14 11:18:26.814 17353-17353/com.ppfa.stdtestca.release I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
09-14 11:18:27.014 17353-17353/com.ppfa.stdtestca.release I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
09-14 11:18:27.214 17353-17353/com.ppfa.stdtestca.release I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
09-14 11:18:27.414 17353-17353/com.ppfa.stdtestca.release I/System.out: debugger has settled (1470)
09-14 11:18:27.444 17353-17353/com.ppfa.stdtestca.release I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.pm.PackageManager.getPackageInstaller, referenced from method com.google.android.gms.common.zze.zzi
09-14 11:18:27.444 17353-17353/com.ppfa.stdtestca.release W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 560: Landroid/content/pm/PackageManager;.getPackageInstaller ()Landroid/content/pm/PackageInstaller;
09-14 11:18:27.444 17353-17353/com.ppfa.stdtestca.release D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x000b
09-14 11:18:27.734 17353-17353/com.ppfa.stdtestca.release I/GMPM: App measurement is starting up, version: 8487
09-14 11:18:27.734 17353-17353/com.ppfa.stdtestca.release I/GMPM: To enable debug logging run: adb shell setprop log.tag.GMPM VERBOSE
09-14 11:18:28.084 17353-17353/com.ppfa.stdtestca.release I/GAv4: Google Analytics 8.4.87 is starting up. To enable debug logging on a device run:
                                                                    adb shell setprop log.tag.GAv4 DEBUG
                                                                    adb logcat -s GAv4
09-14 11:18:28.334 17353-17353/com.ppfa.stdtestca.release I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.app.Notification$Builder.setLocalOnly, referenced from method com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.zza
09-14 11:18:28.334 17353-17353/com.ppfa.stdtestca.release W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 282: Landroid/app/Notification$Builder;.setLocalOnly (Z)Landroid/app/Notification$Builder;
09-14 11:18:28.334 17353-17353/com.ppfa.stdtestca.release D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x00c8
09-14 11:18:28.364 17353-17353/com.ppfa.stdtestca.release I/dalvikvm: Could not find method com.bluerock.sapphire.core.ui.SapphireActivity.checkSelfPermission, referenced from method com.bluerock.sapphire.core.ui.SapphireActivity.getMissingPermissions
09-14 11:18:28.364 17353-17353/com.ppfa.stdtestca.release W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 16675: Lcom/bluerock/sapphire/core/ui/SapphireActivity;.checkSelfPermission (Ljava/lang/String;)I
09-14 11:18:28.364 17353-17353/com.ppfa.stdtestca.release D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x000b
09-14 11:18:28.364 17353-17353/com.ppfa.stdtestca.release I/dalvikvm: Could not find method com.bluerock.sapphire.core.ui.SapphireActivity.requestPermissions, referenced from method com.bluerock.sapphire.core.ui.SapphireActivity.ensurePermissions
09-14 11:18:28.364 17353-17353/com.ppfa.stdtestca.release W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 16694: Lcom/bluerock/sapphire/core/ui/SapphireActivity;.requestPermissions ([Ljava/lang/String;I)V
09-14 11:18:28.364 17353-17353/com.ppfa.stdtestca.release D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0015
09-14 11:18:28.394 17353-17431/com.ppfa.stdtestca.release W/InstanceID/Rpc: Found 10015
09-14 11:18:28.604 17353-17353/com.ppfa.stdtestca.release W/GAv4: Discarding hit. Missing tracking id parameter: t=screenview,a=1215851541,cd=Splash
09-14 11:18:28.644 17353-17353/com.ppfa.stdtestca.release W/GAv4: Discarding hit. Missing tracking id parameter: t=screenview,a=82004195,cd=Splash
09-14 11:18:28.694 17353-17353/com.ppfa.stdtestca.release W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Landroid/view/SearchEvent;)
09-14 11:18:28.694 17353-17353/com.ppfa.stdtestca.release I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.view.Window$Callback.onSearchRequested, referenced from method com.bluerock.sapphire.util.CompositeWindowCallback.onSearchRequested
09-14 11:18:28.694 17353-17353/com.ppfa.stdtestca.release W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve interface method 13048: Landroid/view/Window$Callback;.onSearchRequested (Landroid/view/SearchEvent;)Z
09-14 11:18:28.694 17353-17353/com.ppfa.stdtestca.release D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x72 at 0x0013
09-14 11:18:28.694 17353-17353/com.ppfa.stdtestca.release I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.view.Window$Callback.onWindowStartingActionMode, referenced from method com.bluerock.sapphire.util.CompositeWindowCallback.onWindowStartingActionMode
09-14 11:18:28.694 17353-17353/com.ppfa.stdtestca.release W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve interface method 13052: Landroid/view/Window$Callback;.onWindowStartingActionMode (Landroid/view/ActionMode$Callback;I)Landroid/view/ActionMode;
09-14 11:18:28.694 17353-17353/com.ppfa.stdtestca.release D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x72 at 0x0013
09-14 11:18:28.694 17353-17353/com.ppfa.stdtestca.release D/Activity: #1 setTransGradationModeColor false
09-14 11:18:28.884 17353-17431/com.ppfa.stdtestca.release D/Push: Device registered, token: APA91bG9q6AK2QhIqaF_Ojv9ZM4X8wlLumAdXGu9GYZZf--jkh7QrqHLpAbz3eFU21DWQYNpM0KDLEq69N0reChjbDnUuhgNJjhw1LX-jIBH_7tWV4ex0h2tatojZfKSYnIrL5Sq9P60
09-14 11:18:28.934 17353-17353/com.ppfa.stdtestca.release I/Adreno-EGL: <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:410>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build:  ()
                                                                        OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: E031.24.02.11
                                                                        Build Date: 09/04/14 Thu
                                                                        Local Branch: LA.3.6.1_20140904_070_patches
                                                                        Remote Branch: 
                                                                        Local Patches: 
                                                                        Reconstruct Branch:
```

I am suspecting this is a google play services error of some sort that I am not aware of or based on my research related to this:
[Configure Apps with 64K methods](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html)

Comment: what andorid version you have on your Note4. Is it 6.0 or later?

Comment: the version that I am using is 4.4.4

Comment: Please share what troubleshooting measures have you already done. Since this error only occurs with Galaxy Note 4, as you have said, have you tried checking [Samsung Galaxy Note 4 Troubleshooting](http://thedroidguy.com/samsung-galaxy-note-4-troubleshooting#ProblemsSolutions)?

Comment: So far I have not come across any straight forward measures. The link to my best guess is posted in the issue.